# I cant create a sencha project - sencha touch command not found

Tags: sencha-touch

I have downloaded the sdk and installed the Cmd Version 6.2.0 for Mac. When installing the cmd:

[image]

So I say YES. And I verify it by doing echo $PATH.

But when I type sencha doesnt recognize the command.

-bash: sencha: command not found

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in .bashrc

> export PATH=$PATH:~/sencha/cmd/6.2.1.29/bin